# Ideas standard controller

Tags: apex, standardcontroller, inline-visualforce, ideas

I am building a logic to add an inline visualforce page to Ideas standard layout. I have created a sample visualforce page and added to the page layout, but unfortunately it is not visible when I am viewing Idea records (I am system admin and have access to VF page).

I did some research on developer formus and found `Ideas Visualforce` can only be accomplished using `IdeaStandardController` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_ideastandardcontroller.htm).

I have exactly copied the logic to test the functionality and got the following error when I saved the page and class from dev console:

> common.apex.runtime.bytecode.BytecodeApexObjectType cannot be cast to common.apex.runtime.impl.ApexType

Then I tried to save the VF page from UI instead and see the error:

> Unknown constructor 
>   MyIdeaExtension.MyIdeaExtension(ApexPages.StandardController

I have read the statement in the developer formus:

> The IdeaStandardSetController and IdeaStandardController classes are currently available through a limited release program. For information on enabling these classes for your organization, contact your Salesforce representative.

Do you think I see the error as idea standard controllers are not activated in my Org? I am trying in my Developer Edition , do you know if salesforce will be able to activate this in Developer edition?

**The VF page I have used is :**

The visual force page is:

```
<!-- page named detailPage -->
<apex:page standardController="Idea" extensions="MyIdeaExtension">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Idea Section">
        <ideas:detailOutputLink page="detailPage" ideaId="{!idea.id}">{!idea.title}
        </ideas:detailOutputLink>
        <br/><br/>
        <apex:outputText >{!idea.body}</apex:outputText>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Comments Section">
        <apex:dataList var="a" value="{!modifiedComments}" id="list">
            {!a.commentBody}
        </apex:dataList>
        <ideas:detailOutputLink page="detailPage" ideaId="{!idea.id}" 
            pageOffset="-1">Prev</ideas:detailOutputLink>
        <ideas:detailOutputLink page="detailPage" ideaId="{!idea.id}" 
           pageOffset="1">Next</ideas:detailOutputLink>   
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**The controller:**

```
public class MyIdeaExtension {

    private final ApexPages.IdeaStandardController ideaController;

    public MyIdeaExtension(ApexPages.IdeaStandardController controller) 
    {
        ideaController = (ApexPages.IdeaStandardController)controller;
    }

    public List<IdeaComment> getModifiedComments() 
    {
        IdeaComment[] comments = ideaController.getCommentList(); 
        return comments;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you share the code snippets that did not save for each error message? It looks like you tried different code blocks?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post with any updates.